# How to make a form like this?

Tags: android, android-layout

How to create a form like this with xml?
[image: Uber's driver forum]

Comment: Easiest Way --> By coding.

Comment: @Abhi I meant the most efficient way to get the same results as the GIF

Answer (score 0):

You have to use scrollView that is the efficient way of doing this. Because ScrollView is designed to handle this type of cases.

Answer (score 0):

Use Scroll view and Recycler view to display error message after the validations of fields, You give it a try if still you face any issues do let me know i will look into it.